# Spring Integration filter expression using SPeL

Tags: spring-integration, spring-el

I have a configuration bean that has a list of allowed values:

```
@Component
public class Conf {
    public List<String> getAllowedValues() {
        return Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");
}
```

I have populated my message headers with a field called 'someValue' and I want to use a filter element to exclude messages where someValue is not in the  allowed values list.

My context looks like this:

```
<int:filter expression="#{conf.allowedValues}.contains(headers.get('someValue'))"/>
```

But I get: `SpelParseException: EL1041E:(pos 1): After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'comma(,)'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was provided [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?111669-Spring-Integration-filter-expression-using-SPeL&highlight=):

```
<int:filter expression="@conf.allowedValues.contains(headers.get('someValue'))"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a simpler (maybe not the best) solution for this.

```
<int:filter expression="{"A", "B", "C", "D"}.contains(headers.get('someValue'))" />
```

[reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#d0e11906)